# How to get objects element in akka actor scala

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am new to Akka and scala. I have an API that returns the POJO class. Something like this

```
pathPrefix("dataprofile") {
          get {
            ctx =>
              (sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[Either[Rejection, DataAccessProfile]] map {
                case Left(x) => ctx.reject(x)
                case Right(x) => ctx.complete(x)
              }

          }
        } ~
```

Now I want to use this sActor in some other API and use two of the element(List and String) from DataAccessProfile. And after getting these two elements I want to set it in CompleteInput. I wrote something like

```
pathPrefix("complete") {
          post {
            entity(as[CompleteInput]) { completeInput =>
              complete {
                var session = user.username.get + "_" + account.id.get
                var uNameAccountId = user.username.get +"|" + account.id.get
                if(jwt_token == null || !validateJwt(jwt_token)){
                  jwt_token = encodeJwt(uNameAccountId)
                }
                val result =  (sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[Either[Rejection, DataAccessProfile]]
                implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
                DataAccessProfile future = (DataAccessProfile) Await.result(result, timeout.duration)
                println(future.studyIds)

                autoCompleteService(session,jwt_token,completeInput)
              }
            }
          }
        } ~
```

I am getting an error saying expected ';' but found "."
My question is how we can retrieve element(s) from sActor or any other solution

Now I have tried this:

```
val future2: Future[DataAccessProfile] = (sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[DataAccessProfile]
implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
val result = Await.result(future2, timeout.duration)
println("---------------------------" +result)
```

This time runtime exception saying exception java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast scala.util.Right to com.comprehend.protobuf.rbac.DataAccessProfile

Comment: Is this compilation or run-time error? If compilation, it should show the line, where the problem is. Also please update question with details you found. Thanks!

Comment: it is compilation error. The code which i have written is like the solution i have found. Its like i don't know how to fetch parameters(List<String> and String) from DataAccessProfile

Answer (score 0):

I think you got compilation error at:

```
DataAccessProfile future = (DataAccessProfile) Await.result(result, timeout.duration)
```

it look like more Java style declaration, but because you are writing on Scala it should look like:

```
val future: DataAccessProfile = Await.result(result, timeout.duration).get.asInstanceOf[DataAccessProfile]
```

But, this solution has a number of issues: it is blocking, because it uses await, and it is unsafe, because `Await.result` and `Either.get` can throw an errors, so they need to be properly handled.
I suggest you to take a look closer at this page: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html

And  probably implement something like :

```
 onComplete(result) {
      case Success(Right(profile)) => autoCompleteService(session, jwt_token, completeInput)
      case Success(Left(rejection)) => complete((InternalServerError, "Message was rejected - specify error details here"))
      case Failure(ex)    => complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
    }
```

**UPDATE #1**: 
so the final solution would look like:

```
pathPrefix("complete") {
  post {
    entity(as[CompleteInput]) { completeInput =>
        val session = user.username.get + "_" + account.id.get
        val uNameAccountId = user.username.get +"|" + account.id.get
        if(jwt_token == null || !validateJwt(jwt_token)){
          jwt_token = encodeJwt(uNameAccountId)
        }

        val result =  (sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[Either[Rejection, DataAccessProfile]]

        onComplete(result) {
          case Success(Right(profile)) =>
            println(future.studyIds)
            autoCompleteService(session, jwt_token, completeInput)

          case Success(Left(rejection)) =>
            complete((InternalServerError, "Message was rejected - specify error details here"))

          case Failure(ex) =>
            complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
        }
    }
  }
} ~
```

**UPDATE #2**:
According to your last update, I've removed `Either` usage:

```
pathPrefix("complete") {
  post {
    entity(as[CompleteInput]) { completeInput =>
        val session = user.username.get + "_" + account.id.get
        val uNameAccountId = user.username.get +"|" + account.id.get
        if(jwt_token == null || !validateJwt(jwt_token)){
          jwt_token = encodeJwt(uNameAccountId)
        }

        val result: Future[DataAccessProfile] = (sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[DataAccessProfile]

        onComplete(result) {
          case Success(profile) =>
            println(future.studyIds)
            val updatedInput = completeInput.copy(dataAccessControl = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(list2))
            autoCompleteService(session, jwt_token, updatedInput)

          case Failure(ex) =>
            complete((InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}"))
        }
    }
  }
} ~
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: okay so if i want to have List<String> and String parameter from DataAccessProfile how can i get it from sActor

Comment: @dharmeshmehta  in order to access `DataAccessProfile` object in block `case Success(Right(profile)) ` you can refer to `profile` reference. What exactly did not work, could you specify details, please?

Comment: It say value get is not a member of com.test.protobuf.rbac.DataAccessProfile. I have added this val future2: Future[DataAccessProfile] = (sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[DataAccessProfile]
                    implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
                    val future: DataAccessProfile = Await.result(future2, timeout.duration).get.asInstanceOf[DataAccessProfile]

Comment: I mean in one api that sActor is given the correct response. Only i want to do this just use that sActor again in another api and use its output's parameter

Comment: @dharmeshmehta I've updated the answer with complete code example. Yes, it does not work because you changed `(sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[Either[Rejection, DataAccessProfile]]` to `(sActor ? GetDataAccessProfileByUserAndAccount(account, user)).mapTo[DataAccessProfile]` - so what the response you are expecting from the actor?

Comment: @dharmeshmehta I've put one more code update, according to your question update . Could you take a look at it, please?

Comment: OKay it runs. but how to add future.studyIds in completeInput. completeInput is in request body of api so some values are set from ui and two parameter are set from database how to set those 2 values one is List[String] and other is String

Comment: I tried daliaCompleteInput.dataAccessControl = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(list2); but it says  reassignment to val

Comment: @dharmeshmehta I don't know what `daliaCompleteInput` is - you did not specified any details about this.  But errors says that you want change field which declared as `val` hence can not be changed. I don't know this class API, but I guess it immutable and requires construct new instance with updated field value. Also you did not specify any API for `CompleteInput` - hence I don't know how to change it as well.

Comment: this is case class CompleteInput(sentence: String, startAt: Int, dataAccessControl: List[String]) its completeInput i spelled wrong my apologies

Comment: Ok, so you need to do something like `completeInput.copy(dataAccessControl = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(list2))`  - I've updated the code in answer as well. So, if you need to update case class, use `copy` method - it will construct new instance with updated fields.